# how to drag a button and drop the controls in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have button "textbox".
What I am trying is when i drag that button and drop a text a box must be dropped ..Can anyone help me to solve this..I just tried to drag the button .But the content must be textbox .That I am unable to identify it.

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop ? First result on google search...

Comment: I have looked into it before..What my idea is to drop the input box when a button is dragged

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we will help you from there ;)